# Use SELECT command instead of two OR conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, select, relational-algebra

How can I use SELECT commands or nested SELECTs instead of two conditions combined with **OR**?  I know you can implement **AND** with nested SELECT statements using, for example:

```
select name from (select * from students where grade > C) where age > 25  
-- select name from (select * from students where grade > C) as std1 where age > 25
```

instead of:

```
select name from students where age > 25 and grade > C
```

(only with select command).

But how do you achieve an OR condition without using an OR?

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE age > 25 OR grade > C
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: @Duncan: I believe he's asking "how to rewrite OR by applying a filter to a nested query"

Comment: @Quassnoi: Ah! Your solution in that case is good.

Answer (score 2):

Applying `OR` results in a superset, not a subset, so you cannot achieve the same result by applying a filter to a nested query.

You may rewrite it using a `UNION`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    students
WHERE   age > 25
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    students
WHERE   grade > C
```

is the same as

```
SELECT  *
FROM    students
WHERE   age > 25 OR grade > C
```

, provided there is a `PRIMARY KEY` defined on `students`.

Comment: only with select.  a or b = not( not(a) and not(b) )

Comment: @sohrab: you can't do it by applying a filter to a nested query if that's what you mean.

Comment: not certainly nested query.query that created with select only.i mean rewrite OR with select.maybe like this:a or b = not( not(a) and not(b) )

Comment: Why the 'primary key' condition?  The result will be the same whether there is or is not a PK, won't it?

Comment: @Jonathan: `UNION` will eliminate duplicates which won't be there in case of a PK defined but may be if there is none.

Comment: @sohrab: `NOT (age <= 25 AND grade <> C)` is the same as `age > 25 AND grade > C` if `age` and `grade` are not nullable.